# PYTHON: Creating a dataframe of permutations from a list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, tuples, dataframe, permutation

I am presently trying to create a massive table of permuted values.

```
locA = [1, 2, 3]
locB = [4, 5, 6]
locC = [7, 8, 9]
```

Within 'loc' values are permuted. Each value in a 'loc' is from a different population ('pop1', 'pop2', 'pop3'). So far I have have been able to form a massive list of tuples that combines every within 'loc' rearrangement with every between 'loc' rearrangement.

```
permA = list(itr.permutations(locA, 3))
permB = list(itr.permutations(locB, 3))
permC = list(itr.permutations(locC, 3))
permABC = list(itr.product(permA,permB,permC))

permABC
[((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)),
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 9, 8)),
((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (8, 7, 9)),

    ... etc etc...

((3, 2, 1), (6, 5, 4), (8, 9, 7)),
((3, 2, 1), (6, 5, 4), (9, 7, 8)),
((3, 2, 1), (6, 5, 4), (9, 8, 7))]
```

I have been trying to get this into a Pandas DataFrame, but I am having trouble iterating through the list of tuples to get into a DataFrame. :(

Ideal format:

```
loc  pop1  pop2  pop3
A    1     2     3    |
B    4     5     6    |>>>> permABC[0]
C    7     8     9    |

... etc etc ...

A    3     2     1    |
B    6     5     4    |>>>> permABC[215]
C    9     8     7    |
```

My problem is getting the list of tuples into a dataframe. I need to get every combination possible of 'loc'. E.g. all possible rearrangements of 'locA' with rearrangements of 'locB' with rearrangements of 'locC'.

To put this into perspective, for any particular permutation for each population, I'll need to make calculations. For sake of argument, in the above, for 'perABC[0]' and 'permABC[215],' mean for 'pop1' would be 4 and 6 respectively.

I'm just not sure how to do this on the fly and currently at my level of coding its easier to anchor things into a dataframe that I can manipulate. I have tried playing with using indexes to pull out population specific info for any given permutation in 'permABC', e.g.

```
for item in permABC[0]:
    print item[0]
    1
    4
    7
```

Which works, but using this method isn't feasible because you can't do any functions on them; returns TypeError "'int' object is not iterable".

Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know pandas, but you can simplify that permutation product code: `product(*[permutations(u) for u in (locA, locB, locC)])`.

Comment: "but I am having trouble" What kind of trouble? Memory errors? Computation time? Your toes are cold?

Comment: @PM2Ring, thanks for that! Could you please explain how the '*' works in this line of code? I think this simplification may be what I need to do what I need to do -- see my edit above.

Comment: The `*` unpacks a list (or other iterable) of args into separate args, so `f(*[a,b,c]) is equivalent to f(a,b,c)`; some people call it the "splat" operator. See [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) (& the previous section) in the official Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If your trouble is related to performance or memory:

I think the problem is that you take a generator `itr.permutations` and convert the whole thing to a list:

```
permC = list(itr.permutations(locC, 3))
```

Thereby destroying the whole point of a generator.

You should process each permutation as it is generated, then throw it away. This will decrease your memory profile dramatically and also speed up your computation.

```
for pair in itr.permutations(locC, 3):
    # Do your stuff
```

In the above code, each pair does only exist for the duration of the iteration, after that the next pair is generated.

Comment: Hi @firelynx. Thanks for the comment. At the moment it's not so much computation power - though you raise a good point and I think this could be an issue in the future. My problem is that I need to make calculations  using any given permutation of 'loc' for a particular 'pop'. My level of coding has prevented me figuring out how to do this on the fly. Hopefully my edit above has made things clearer.